# How was the first Malbolge interpreter tested?

Tags: testing

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge), Malbolge was so difficult to understand when it arrived that it took two years for the first Malbolge program to appear.

If this is true, how was [the first Malbolge interpreter](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge_interp.html) tested (to check if it did the right thing when a Malbolge program was given)? Was it tested at all?

Comment: One might suggest adding [quality-assurance], but it sounds kind of weird when dealing with Malbolge.

Comment: @Williham: Depends on your interpretation.  One might wish to test it to assure that its quality is as diabolical and its user experience as frustrating as possible. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested against what?  Wikipedia notes that the official specification and the interpreter do not match precisely.  When you consider that the language was named after Dante's eight circle of Hell and designed to be needlessly complicated and difficult to use, it's likely that any such discrepancies are by design, which is kind of antithetical to the purposes of testing.